# Using ?= in javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

in javascript

```js
console.log(/x(?=b[1-9])/.test('xb2')); // true

console.log(/x(?=b[1-9])$/.test('xb2')); // false
```

what is difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first pattern `x(?=b[1-9])` matches `x` which is then followed by `b` and a digit.  The input `xb2` matches this.

The second pattern `x(?=b[1-9])$` is conflicting, and can never match anything.  This pattern says to match:

```regex
x           the letter x
(?=b[1-9])  assert that b and 1-9 follows
$           match end of the input
```

It is impossible for `b[1-9]` to follow `x` while at the same time `x` is the end of the input.  Use the first version in your question.